# nginx serving wrong certificate for vitual hosts with own conf file

Tags: nginx, centos7, virtualhost, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've got a few virtual hosts set up through nginx on my centos7 server. I'm getting certs by using letsencrypt certbot. By default certbot writes the vhost info to the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. This isn't the behavior I want. I use the `/sites-available` and `/site-enabled` folders with separate .conf files for each vhost. If I connect to a site in which the vhost and ssl info is listed in the `nginx.conf` it works fine. However if I copy the directives out and put them in a new conf file in the `site-available` folder (with a symlink in `sites-enabled`) it serves up the wrong certificate. It serves the one related to another vhost. I'd really like to keep my vhost configs in separate files rather than building them into the nginx.conf, but I can't seem to make that work.

---

UPDATE:

As requested here is the contents of my `nginx -T` call. None of the server blocks that are outside the conf are shown here though. They're loaded via the line that reads `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf`.

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;


    server {
        server_name stairwell-soundboard-api.lonewolfdigital.com; # managed by Certbot
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stairwell-soundboard-api.lonewolfdigital.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stairwell-soundboard-api.lonewolfdigital.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }

    server {
        if ($host = stairwell-soundboard-api.lonewolfdigital.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        listen       80 ;
        listen       [::]:80 ;
        server_name stairwell-soundboard-api.lonewolfdigital.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }

}

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-perl.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-mail.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-stream.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so";

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers "THIS-CONTENT-REMOVED";
```

---

UPDATE 2

my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com.conf file

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com; # managed by Certbot
    root /opt/soundboard-player/build;
    index index.html index.htm;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com/fullchain.pem; #managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com/privkey.pem; #managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen       80 ;
    listen       [::]:80 ;
    server_name stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

---

UPDATE 3:

As requested here's the output of the two folders

sites-available:

```
➜  ~ cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
➜  sites-available ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  612 Feb 15  2018 draft.indygaa.com.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1492 Oct 28 14:49 fullcontactmotherhood.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  424 Oct 25  2017 indygaa.com.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  639 Sep  7  2019 lonewolfdigital.com.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  996 Oct 29 21:43 stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  556 Oct 27 20:39 webhooks.lonewolfdigital.com.conf
```

sites-enabled:

```
➜  sites-available cd ../sites-enabled
➜  sites-enabled ls -l
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Oct 29 21:05 fullcontactmotherhood.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/fullcontactmotherhood.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Oct 29 21:44 lonewolfdigital.com.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/lonewolfdigital.com.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 74 Oct 28 15:33 stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 60 Oct 29 21:07 webhooks.lonewolfdigital.com.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/webhooks.lonewolfdigital.com.conf
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've added the output, but it doesn't actually show the blocks that are loaded from external .conf files. The issue is I have 3 external .conf files as well. Each of these is set up for .ssl. However no matter which of those sites I go to it will only serve up the certificate for one of the hosts. If I take the blocks out of external files and put them in the global nginx.conf file it works fine though.

Comment: All of them should have shown up there in `nginx -T` if they were properly symlinked. Check your symlinks, and check ownership and permissions on the files and containing directories.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the original files are all owned/grouped to root with 644 permissions. The symlink has the same ownership with a 777 permission.

Comment: Additionally, the symlinks all use absolute paths so there shouldn't be any confusion there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I checked again, and it appears that when I did that `nginx -T` I only had one site in the sites-enabled, and it is the problematic one. I added some others and their configs show when I run the command now except for the problematic one. I'm attaching the problematic one to this post because I can't see anything wrong with it, but it isn't being loaded.

Comment: Please, show the output of these commands: `ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-available` and  `ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Comment: @JesúsÁngel I've added the output you requested.

Comment: Nginx includes only the files ending in `.conf`, while the name of your "problematic" config file ends in `.com`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have been banging my head against my desk for days. I knew it was something very simple, and I can't believe I missed that. Please make that an answer and I'll mark it correct so you can get the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your include line is `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;` so you are including files ending in .conf. As I requested, your sites-enabled vhost configuration files are:

```
➜  sites-available cd ../sites-enabled
➜  sites-enabled ls -l
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Oct 29 21:05 fullcontactmotherhood.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/fullcontactmotherhood.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Oct 29 21:44 lonewolfdigital.com.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/lonewolfdigital.com.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 74 Oct 28 15:33 stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 60 Oct 29 21:07 webhooks.lonewolfdigital.com.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/webhooks.lonewolfdigital.com.conf`
```

Note that stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com does not end in .conf but .com. Delete the link and make a new one which ends in .conf and reload your nginx:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/stairwell-soundboard-player.lonewolfdigital.com
systemctl reload nginx
```